# Merging a branch and a branch off that branch back to the trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch, trunk

We have a project in SVN, and we work out of the trunk. I had to cut a branch for a release, let's call it branch A. A little later I had to cut another branch off of branch A. Let's call it branch B. Assume that some files have been modified in all 3 places, and some files have been added in one branch but not the other.

It's now time to merge both branches back to the trunk. What is the proper way to go about this? Should I merge branch B back into branch A first, and then merge the result of that into the trunk? Or should I merge one branch into the trunk and then the other? Does the order matter?

I know that this is likely to be a messy merge with lots of conflicts. But I'd like to make it as painless as possible. I'm really not very experienced with SVN or source control in general, so I'd appreciate any pointers you could give. I suppose the answer could depend on *what* has changed in each place, but if there's any general wisdom on how to manage branches and do merges like this I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Order will only matter in one place: you don't want to merge a file addition twice, or you'll get a hard-to-resolve "tree conflict". Since there was a file addition on only one branch, you should be able to merge in whatever order you want. The revisions common to your two branches will come along in merge history regardless of which branch you merge first.